# Calculating time slept

Tags: r

I am in the process of calculating time slept from Bed.time and Waking.up.time, these two columns are in a larger data set.

I transform them into a new data set and convert them to numerical data, ommitting NAs

```
bed <- data.frame(gsub(":","",as.character(proj.data$Bed.time)))
lapply(bed, as.numeric)
colnames(bed)[1]<-"Bed"
#View(bed)

wake <- data.frame(gsub(":","",as.character(proj.data$Waking.up.time)))
lapply(wake, as.numeric)
colnames(wake)[1]<-"Wake"
#View(wake)

timing <-data.frame(bed,wake)
#View(timing)
as.numeric(na.omit(timing$Bed))
as.numeric(na.omit(timing$Wake))
```

Below is where have encountered a problem, I don't believe my function(y) works:

```
# convert columns to seconds
convert = do.call(data.frame, lapply(timing, lubridate::seconds))

sleeping<- function(x){
  (as.numeric(substring(1,2)) * 60) + as.numeric(substring(3,4))
}
sleeping2<- function(y){
  (as.numeric(substring(1,2)) * 60) - as.numeric(substring(3,4))
}
```

In the ifelse statement if the value of Wake is larger then Bed, my function(x) is applied and Wake(x[2]) - Bed(x[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AtmJ.png)]). With my y function I am trying to do the opposite Bed(x[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AtmJ.png)]) - Wake(x[2]).

```
# get time diff
timing$time_slept <- ifelse(timing$Wake > timing$Bed, apply(convert, 1, function(x) x[2] - x[1]), apply(convert, 1, function(y) y[1] - y[2]))
View(timing)
```

However, data output (timing) looks like this:
[image: timing output]

In somecases my calculations are a success but in others, as you can see the values are minused from eachother in the wrong order e.g. row 1 2345-0645=1700

Comment: Can you provide (a sample) with `dput(timing)`?

Comment: > Hope this helps!         structure(list(Bed = c("2345", "2300", "2130", "0000", "0115", "2330", "0100", "2300", "0330", "0130", "0100", "0215",), Wake = c("0645", "0800", "0500", "0730", "0915", "0900", "0930", 
"0630", "0900", "0830", "0600", "1050"), time_slept = c(1700, 
1500, 1630, 730, 800, 1430, 830, 1670, 570, 700, 500, 835)), row.names = c(NA, -134L), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: Deleting the `:` and converting a parseable time like `23:00` to a string like `"2300"` seems like a really bad first step. Could you share a `dput` of your **original** data?

Comment: Bed.time: c("23:45", "23:00", "21:30", "00:00", "01:15", "23:30", "01:00", 
"23:00", "03:30", "01:30", "01:00", "02:15") Waking.up.time: ("06:45", "08:00", "05:00", "07:30", "09:15", "09:00", "09:30", 
"06:30", "09:00", "08:30", "06:00", "10:50"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Transform character vectors to a date-time object

```
bed <- lubridate::parse_date_time(bed, '%H%M')
wake <- lubridate::parse_date_time(wake, '%H%M')
```

2 - Calculate time difference

```
time_diff <- wake - bed
```

3 - Correct negative values by adding 24 hours.

```
time_diff_corrected <- ifelse(time_diff < 0, time_diff + 24, time_diff)
```